# Appending options to order table using the woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to add a few options to the orders list in the customer's account page, sadly im not being able to and can't find any information online.

Im attempting this hooking a function into the `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions` like this:

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'mw_add_invoice_button_to_list' );
function ( $actions )
{
  $actions[] = array(
    "url" => "testURL",
    "name" => "testNAME"
  );
  return $actions;
}
```

Im quite new to using filters so this is probably a simply mistake, can you help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed it is a very simple mistake :) . You forgot to add the name of the function

`function ( $actions )`  ??

try

`function mw_add_invoice_button_to_list ( $actions )`

Answer (score 2):

Or another choose options.

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', function ( $actions ) {
  $actions[] = array(
    "url" => "testURL",
    "name" => "testNAME"
  );
  return $actions;
}, 10, 2 );
```